# Harddisk life span Striping vs Spanning

Tags: hard-drive, raid

Will striping two disks reduce life span of a disk due to increased write load compared to spanning where the disks are filled one by one?

Comment: Disks are always spinning, regardless of actual writing/reading operations. Not sure if reading/writing can alter substantially the life-time of disks, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't found any report on the specifics of striping vs life-span, let's consider that the adjacent problem is one of I/O, more specifically if the drives might deteriorate faster if more data is written to them.

This being said, magnetic disks spin several platters installed in a central axis, regardless of whether you actually are writing any sort of data. Why? Stopping the motor when you don't need the drive is.

1. Time consuming

   - The motor needs to suddenly stop, thereby canceling all inertia of the disks. Stopping them in an instant would most likely shatter them, as they are running at speeds of 5000RPM. So, they need to be stopped somewhat slowly (5 to 10 seconds).
2. Energy inefficient

   - Starting the motor costs more energy by unit of time than simply running it at full speed at all times (an good analogy would be the florescent bulb problem: it costs more at start, but the savings are great in the long run).

I got the following from [TechArp](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=84). Quoting the relevant entries:

> Myth #6 :
>   Downloading too much *stuff* from the Internet will reduce your hard disk drive's lifespan.
>
> Truth :
>   Downloading "stuff" into your hard disk drive all the time will not reduce its lifespan. Even filling up the hard disk drive completely will not make a difference in its reliability.
>
> Hard drives are like a car's fuel tank. They are designed to store data, like the fuel tank is designed to store fuel. Will your car be more likely to die if you keep filling it up with fuel, or even fill it up completely? Illogical, isn't it?

---

> Myth #21 :
>   Scanning for viruses several times a day can kill your hard disk drive.
>
> Truth :
>   Scanning for viruses is no different from any other operations that requires reading data from the hard disk drive. Therefore, the act of scanning viruses is no less likely to kill your hard disk drive than it is to prevent YOU from catching a cold.
>
> With that said, unnecessarily scanning the hard disk drive continuously will increase the operating temperature of the hard disk drive. Over a long time, the sustained high temperature can reduce the lifespan of your hard disk drive.

With Solid State Drives (SSD), they behave more like flash drives and, in them, successive read/write cycles ***will*** eventually deteriorate the electronic components that control it's memory. Earlier models using Intel controllers or JMicron chips suffered heavily from performance issues due to poor handling.